# Why does this code run so slow when it is run 1000 times a second?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, opengl-es

So I have this code that builds arrays with vertex data for the gpu.  Right now the amount of particles I can have is severely limited by the CPU, specifically this function.

This function basically overwrites values in a pre-allocated array (way more efficient then appending I think) based on the values in an array of "Particle" Objects.

```
    circles = [GLfloat](count:  ((MAX_PARTICLES) * 8) * 2, repeatedValue: 0)
    squares = [GLfloat](count:  ((MAX_PARTICLES) * (6 * 4)), repeatedValue: 0)
    indices = [GLushort](count:  ((MAX_PARTICLES) * 6), repeatedValue: 0)
```

Surprisingly it is not the obj.update(1 / 60.0) call that is causing this latency, and the "calcRectangle" seems to be going as fast as possible.  Is their any way to speed up this code, or is this the limit of modern swift?

```
    private func _buildArrays1()
    {
        var circlePos:Int = 0
        var rectPos:Int = 0
        var buffer_index:Int = 0
        var accum:Int = 0
for obj in particles
{
    obj.update(1.0 / 60.0)
    let pos:Point = obj.position
    let lpos:Point = obj.lastPosition
    var color:ColorHSV = obj.color
    let width:GLfloat = obj.size
    let rect = Math.makeRectangle(pos, p2: lpos, w: width)

    color = ColorHSV(h: 1.0, s: 0.0, v: 0.0, a: 1.0)
    circles[circlePos] = pos.x
    circles[circlePos + 1] = pos.y
    circles[circlePos + 2] = 0.0
    circles[circlePos + 3] = color.h
    circles[circlePos + 4] = color.s
    circles[circlePos + 5] = color.v
    circles[circlePos + 6] = color.a
    circles[circlePos + 7] = width
    circles[circlePos + 8] = lpos.x
    circles[circlePos + 9] = lpos.y
    circles[circlePos + 10] = 0.0
    circles[circlePos + 11] = color.h
    circles[circlePos + 12] = color.s
    circles[circlePos + 13] = color.v
    circles[circlePos + 14] = color.a
    circles[circlePos + 15] = width
    circlePos += 16

    color = ColorHSV(h: 1.0, s: 1.0, v: 0.0, a: 1.0)

    squares[rectPos] = rect.0.x; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = rect.0.y; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.h; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.s; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.v; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.a; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = rect.1.x; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = rect.1.y; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.h; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.s; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.v; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.a; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = rect.2.x; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = rect.2.y; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.h; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.s; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.v; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.a; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = rect.3.x; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = rect.3.y; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.h; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.s; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.v; rectPos += 1;
    squares[rectPos] = color.a; rectPos += 1;

    indices[buffer_index] = GLushort(accum); buffer_index += 1;
    indices[buffer_index] = GLushort(accum + 1); buffer_index += 1;
    indices[buffer_index] = GLushort(accum + 2); buffer_index += 1;
    indices[buffer_index] = GLushort(accum + 3); buffer_index += 1;
    indices[buffer_index] = GLushort(accum + 2); buffer_index += 1;
    indices[buffer_index] = GLushort(accum + 1); buffer_index += 1;


    accum += 4;
}
}
```

And just incase (Though i doubt the issue is here) here is the relevant excerpts from the math class.

```
class Math {
    static func makeRectangle(p1: Point, p2: Point, w: GLfloat) -> (Point, Point, Point, Point)
    {
        //Returns the vertices of a rectangle made with the two point
        if ((p2.x < p1.x) && (p2.y < p1.y))
        {
            //POINTs are not in the right order
            return makeRectangle(p2, p2: p1, w: w)
        }
        let vector = subtract(p2, p1)
        let unit = devide(vector, length(vector))
        let perp = Point(x: -unit.y, y: unit.x)
        let calc = multiply(perp, w / 2)
        return (add(p1, calc), subtract(p1, calc), add(p2, calc), r: subtract(p2, calc))
    }
    static func subtract(l:Point, _ r:Point) -> Point
    {
        return Point(x: l.x - r.x, y: l.y - r.y)
    }
    static func add(l:Point, _ r:Point) -> Point
    {
        return Point(x: r.x + l.x, y: r.y + l.y)
    }
    static func devide(l:Point, _  r:GLfloat) -> Point
    {
        return Point(x: l.x / r, y: l.y / r)
    }
    static func length(o:Point) -> GLfloat
    {
        return sqrt(o.x * o.x + o.y * o.y)
    }
    static func multiply(o:Point, _ v:GLfloat) -> Point
    {
        return Point(x: o.x * v, y: o.y * v)
    }
}
```

Comment: How many `particles` do you have? Running the entire code 1000 times a second is pretty often - and you are doing a lot of work. Particle systems are a quite difficult task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was sitting in a lecture (That I was totally paying attention to) when I had a realization, why am I holding everything in structs, why not hold position directly in the array for the gpu.

SO I got rid of the "Point" struct and had everything be based on array locations! Now the bottleneck is in the gpu!

It simply is not efficient to store values in a struct, then copy them component by component into an array.